# Difference between value and cacheName param of @Cacheable annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am new to @Cacheable and @CacheEvict annotations which we use for caching in Spring framework. But while looking into its implementation and  parameters that @Cacheable uses ***what is the difference between value and cacheName params of @Cacheable annotation***?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By taking a look into [Cacheable documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) **value** is an
Alias for **cacheNames** which means that both are tied to the same object.

- [values](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#value--)
- [cacheNames](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#cacheNames--)

**Value:**

```
@AliasFor(value="cacheNames")
public abstract java.lang.String[] value
Alias for cacheNames().
Default:
{}
```